# No output from non standard File Descriptor

Tags: unix, rust

I am having issues receiving data from the child process.

To send a string to the child process you write to `FD3` and it will output the result to `FD4`.

The child process runs fine, and if it couldn't write to `FD4`, the process would not start correctly, so `FD4` has to be available but I just don't know why no output is given.

My initial thoughts is when sending the string (to `FD3`) it wasn't null byte terminating therefore not receiving the string correctly (and then not sending anything back on `FD4`) but I am sure I am doing it correctly.

I have tested writing to `FD4` within the child process manually and the parent receives the output.

```
use nix::fcntl::FcntlArg::{F_SETFD};
use nix::fcntl::{fcntl, open, FdFlag, OFlag};
use nix::sys::socket::{socketpair, AddressFamily, SockFlag, SockType};
use nix::sys::stat::Mode;
use nix::unistd::{close, dup2, execvp, fork, pipe, read, write, ForkResult};
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::unix::io::RawFd;
use std::process::abort;

fn main() {
    let input_socket: (RawFd, RawFd) = create_socket();
    let output_socket: (RawFd, RawFd) = create_socket();

    match fork() {
        Ok(ForkResult::Parent { child, .. }) => {
            println!("Child PID: {}", child);

            close(input_socket.1).unwrap();
            close(output_socket.1).unwrap();

            let test = r#"{"id":0,"method":"Target.getTargets"}\0"#;
            write(input_socket.0, test.as_bytes()).expect("unable to write");

            let mut buf = [0; 64];
            read(output_socket.0, &mut buf).unwrap();
            println!("BUFFER: {:#?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());
        }
        Ok(ForkResult::Child) => {
            setup_child(input_socket.1, output_socket.1);
            abort()
        }
        Err(err) => { println!("{}", err); abort()},
    }
}

#[cfg(any(
    target_os = "android",
    target_os = "dragonfly",
    target_os = "emscripten",
    target_os = "freebsd",
    target_os = "linux",
    target_os = "netbsd",
    target_os = "openbsd"
))]
fn create_socket() -> (RawFd, RawFd) {
    socketpair(
        AddressFamily::Unix,
        SockType::Stream,
        None,
        SockFlag::SOCK_CLOEXEC,
    )
    .unwrap()
}

#[cfg(any(target_os = "ios", target_os = "macos"))]
fn create_socket() -> (RawFd, RawFd) {
    let socket = socketpair(
        AddressFamily::Unix,
        SockType::Stream,
        None,
        SockFlag::empty(),
    )
    .unwrap();
    fcntl(socket.0, F_SETFD(FdFlag::FD_CLOEXEC)).unwrap();
    fcntl(socket.1, F_SETFD(FdFlag::FD_CLOEXEC)).unwrap();
    socket
}

fn setup_child(input: RawFd, output: RawFd) {
    let _input: RawFd = dup2(input, 3).unwrap();
    let _output: RawFd = dup2(output, 4).unwrap();

    let file = CString::new("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome").unwrap();

    let arg1 = CString::new("--remote-debugging-pipe").unwrap();
    let arg2 = CString::new("--enable-logging=stderr").unwrap();
    let args = vec![arg1.as_c_str(),arg2.as_c_str()];

    let _res = execvp(&file, &args).unwrap();
}
```

This is the open FDs for the child process: `lsof -p 14620`

```
COMMAND PID  USER   FD     TYPE DEVICE                  SIZE/OFF                  NODE NAME
Chrome 14620 tom    0      PIPE 0xcafab653bf79be56      16384                     ->0xfc41206e43b6bb9d
Chrome 14620 tom    1      PIPE 0x71c3c6a8bffbf5ad      16384                     ->0x587f975b5bfd4499
Chrome 14620 tom    2      PIPE 0x71c3c6a8bffbf5ad      16384                     ->0x587f975b5bfd4499
Chrome 14620 tom    3u     unix 0x36cd3ac44c49d68d        0t0                     ->0x36cd3ac44c49f2ad
Chrome 14620 tom    4u     unix 0x36cd3ac44c49dc05        0t0                     ->0x36cd3ac44c49f9b5
```

**UPDATE**

I found the issue, for some reason the first argument when running the chrome process was being ignored?? So when I place any other argument as the first in the list chrome actually starts up the remote debugging. Weird issue!

When I run the chrome process in terminal with `--remote-debugging-pipe` as the first argument it works fine too, so why does it happen when i use: `execvp(&file, &args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how I am running the process.

`execvp(&file, &args)` requires the first arg to be the file location. Thanks to: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541910/how-to-use-execvp)

Changing this code makes everything run as expected:

```
let args = vec![file.as_c_str(), arg1.as_c_str(),arg2.as_c_str()];
```