# Reading from Standard Input and storing each word in a separate column of an array

Tags: c, execvp

Lets say I have a buffer and some other pointer for storing the stdin:

```
char buffer[256];
char *command[3];
```

And I'm reading from stdin into buffer:

```
fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin);
```

If stdin was `ls -s1`, I want to have `command[0]="ls"` and `command[1]="-s1"`. I also want `command[2]=NULL`.

For context I am trying to use `execvp()` later on so I want all the commands separated in `command` with the null character at the end.

Could someone please let me know how could I go about saving the commands in the command array in that order?

Comment: use strtok function to tokenize the input

Comment: Yes, with the separating the input. but when I try to use `execvp()`, I get this warning: `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘execvp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] execvp(commands[0],commands);`

Comment: See [How to use execvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541910/how-to-use-execvp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    
    char buffer[256];
    char *command[3];
    int i=0;

    fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
    char *p = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    if (p)  *p = 0;
    char *token=strtok(buffer," ");
    command[0]=strdup(token);
    printf("%s\n",command[0] );
    while(token!=NULL){
        
        token=strtok(NULL," ");
        if(token!=NULL){

            command[++i]=strdup(token);
            printf("%s\n", command[i]);
        }
    }
    command[2]=NULL;
    execvp(command[0],command);
    return 0;
}
```